# copying text to clipboard

Tags: java, macos, copy, clipboard, toolkit

I am trying to create a `JMenuItem` for **Copy**.
But the selected text in the `JTextArea` doesn't seems to be copied.

```
String toCopy = textarea.getSelectedText();
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(toCopy);
Clipboard clpbrd = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ().getSystemClipboard ();
clpbrd.setContents (stringSelection, null);
```

I tried changing it to this:

```
String toCopy = "Testing";
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(toCopy);
Clipboard clpbrd = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ().getSystemClipboard ();
clpbrd.setContents (stringSelection, null);
```

As expected it fails too.
I believe that the `Clipboard` and `Toolkit` is the one that is causing the problem.
Or could it be that i am using a mac?
I have seen these codes on websites saying the codes are for windows, but not for mac?

Answer (score 0):

Try the next:

```
textarea.copy();
```

From [javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.copy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#copy%28%29)

> Transfers the currently selected range in the associated
>         text model to the system clipboard, leaving the contents
>         in the text model.  The current selection remains intact.
>         Does nothing for `null` selections.